# How to implement bitwise operations on a bitflags enum?

Tags: rust

I have an enum that looks like this:

```
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum PublicFlags {
    PublicFlagVersion = 0x01,
    PublicFlagReset = 0x02,
    NoncePresent = 0x04,
    IdPresent = 0x08,
    PktNumLen4 = 0x30,
    PktNumLen2 = 0x20,
    PktNumLen1 = 0x10,
    Multipath = 0x40,
}
```

I want to do a bitwise operation on several of the enum values. However, the Rust compiler complains:

```
an implementation of `std::ops::BitAnd` might be missing for `PublicFlags`.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An `enum` in Rust is not intended to be used as bit flags. `PublicFlags` can *only* take the values given in the enum (and not a combination). So for instance, the following match statement is exhaustive:

```
let flags: PublicFlags;
...
match flags {
    PublicFlagVersion => {...}
    PublicFlagReset => {...}
    NoncePresent => {...}
    IdPresent => {...}
    PktNumLen4 => {...}
    PktNumLen2 => {...}
    PktNumLen1 => {...}
    Multipath => {...}
}
```

There is no way to have a `PublicFlags` variable with a combination of the flags.

The solution is to actually store the value as a `u8`, then use constants to store the value of each flag. This can be cumbersome, but thankfully the [bitflags](https://docs.rs/bitflags/latest/bitflags/) crate wraps all the boilerplate up in a macro for you. Here is an example how you would create your struct using bitflags:

```rust
bitflags::bitflags! {
    #[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
    struct PublicFlags: u8 {
        const PUBLIC_FLAG_VERSION = 0x01;
        const PUBLIC_FLAG_RESET = 0x02;
        const NONCE_PRESENT = 0x04;
        const ID_PRESENT = 0x08;
        const PKT_NUM_LEN_4 = 0x30;
        const PKT_NUM_LEN_2 = 0x20;
        const PKT_NUM_LEN_1 = 0x10;
        const MULTIPATH = 0x40;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let flag = PublicFlags::PUBLIC_FLAG_VERSION | PublicFlags::ID_PRESENT;
    assert!((flag & PublicFlags::MULTIPATH).is_empty()); 
    assert!(flag.contains(PublicFlags::ID_PRESENT));
}
```

Comment: Excellent! This works! I was also able to just cast the enum to `u8`.

Comment: @BrettJackson make sure to also flag the enum with `#[repr(u8)]`

Answer (score 12):

This could work as an alternative answer without new dependencies.

```rust
pub mod PublicFlags {
    pub const PublicFlagVersion: u8 = 0x01;
    pub const PublicFlagReset: u8 = 0x02;
    pub const NoncePresent: u8 = 0x04;
    pub const IdPresent: u8 = 0x08;
    pub const PktNumLen4: u8 = 0x30;
    pub const PktNumLen2: u8 = 0x20;
    pub const PktNumLen1: u8 = 0x10;
    pub const Multipath: u8 = 0x40;
}
```

You can refer to the values just like with an enum with `PublicFlags::PublicFlagVersion`, or add `use PublicFlags::*;` if it is cleaner to reference the values without specifying the namespace.

Comment: This solution has one big drawback: When using a match statement, the compiler can detect missing cases if you are using enums. This won't work with this solution.

Comment: @Phidelux The point with flags is that you combine them, which isn't possible with enums. Just matching the individual flags would be a senseless thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this existed back then, but a bit of `as` magic does the job without any bitor/bitand trait implementation (makes the code a bit longer but it is very simple)

```rust
enum BITS {
    ONE = 0b0001,
    TWO = 0b0010,
    FOUR = 0b0100,
    EIGHT = 0b1000,
}

fn main() {
    let flags: u8;

    flags = BITS::ONE as u8 | BITS::FOUR as u8 | BITS::EIGHT as u8;

    println!("{flags:b}")

    use_flags(flags);
}

fn use_flags(flags:u8){
    let flag_one = flags & BITS::ONE as u8 == 1;
    if flag_one {
        println!("flag ONE is {flag_one}")
    }
}
```

PS: you will get warning of this shape if you don't use all enums in the code: "warning: variant `TWO` is never constructed", but, again, it is just a warning that can be handled gracefully.

NOTE: when using enums for bitwise operations, item values should not overlap. In the code of the main question, at least `PktNumLen1` will overlap with `PublicFlagReset` and `IdPresent`, 0x10 is 0b1010, 0x8 is 0b1000, and 0x2 is 0b0010 (2nd and 4th bits overlap)

Comment: This has always existed, but this doesn't produce an instance of the enum but an `i8`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I don't get what you mean by this: "this doesn't produce an instance of the enum", because combining flag values is expected to produce something not in the enum, ie 13 is the flag result of my example code which is not part of BITS enum.

Comment: I expanded my answer with an example function and a note

Comment: I changed i8 to u8 to also use the 8th bit :) I was too eager to post an answer I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I have already an answer here on how to setup and use an enum if we want bitwise operations.

On the other hand, we can combine enum values in a vector (dynamic array) and use them as they are:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum BITS {
    ONE = 0b0001,
    TWO = 0b0010,
    FOUR = 0b0100,
    EIGHT = 0b1000,
}

fn main() {
    let flags: Vec<BITS>;

    flags = vec![BITS::ONE, BITS::FOUR, BITS::EIGHT];

    println!("{flags:?}");

    use_flags(flags);
}

fn use_flags(flags:Vec<BITS>){
    for flag in flags{
        match flag {
            BITS::ONE => println!("flag ONE is set"),
            BITS::TWO => println!("flag TWO is set"),
            BITS::FOUR => println!("flag FOUR is set"),
            BITS::EIGHT => println!("flag EIGHT is set")
        }
    }
}
```

the thing here is to set default values (with mut) inside our function and use the `match` to customize them later down the code.

it is easy to code but the downside of this approach is the memory usage for each flag inside the vector.

in the bit operation approach, bits of enum values should not overlap. the forethought process is essential in that approach. and also unpacking bit fields is not easy, yet storing them in bit fields makes it efficient for memory. so check my other answer too. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76603396/9512475)

Comment: This seems like a terrible solution to the problem. You use eight times the memory, and finding if a particular bit is set is O(n) instead of O(1). Also, there is no reason to use different bits for each option because they exist in seperate `u8`s. If memory wasn't a concern then the poster could just have used a struct or array of bools.

Comment: @jacob, RUST is not as easy to work with as C/C++. I would like to see your implementation, so please add your own answer to this topic and ping me in the comments so that we can benefit a better solution all together.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [bitflags](https://crates.io/crates/bitflags) mentioned in another answer you can youse [enumflags2](https://crates.io/crates/enumflags2). The latter is based on enums.

```rust
use enumflags2::{bitflags, BitFlags};

#[bitflags]
#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Flags {
    Bit1 = 1 << 7,
    Bit2 = 1 << 6,
    Bit3 = 1 << 5,
    Bit4 = 1 << 4,
    Bit5 = 1 << 3,
    Bit6 = 1 << 2,
    Bit7 = 1 << 1,
    Bit8 = 1,
}

fn main() {
    let flags_1_2: BitFlags<Flags> = Flags::Bit1 | Flags::Bit2;
    let flags_2_3: BitFlags<Flags> = Flags::Bit2 | Flags::Bit3;

    assert!(flags_1_2.contains(Flags::Bit1));
    assert!(!flags_1_2.contains(Flags::Bit3));

    // Union of two flag sets
    assert!((flags_1_2 | flags_2_3).contains(Flags::Bit1 | Flags::Bit2 | Flags::Bit3));
    // Intersection of two flag sets
    assert_eq!(flags_1_2 & flags_2_3, Flags::Bit2);
    // Flip flags
    assert!((!flags_1_2).contains(Flags::Bit3 | Flags::Bit4 | Flags::Bit5 /* and so on */));

    // You can still use your original enum
    let enum_flags = Flags::Bit1;
    // Here match guards are unions of enum variants but arm values are `BitFlags`
    let bitflags_from_enum = match enum_flags {
        Flags::Bit1 | Flags::Bit2 | Flags::Bit3 => Flags::Bit1 | Flags::Bit2 | Flags::Bit3,
        Flags::Bit4 | Flags::Bit5 | Flags::Bit6 => Flags::Bit4 | Flags::Bit5 | Flags::Bit6,
        Flags::Bit7 | Flags::Bit8 => Flags::Bit7 | Flags::Bit8,
    };
    assert!(bitflags_from_enum.contains(Flags::Bit1 | Flags::Bit2 | Flags::Bit3));
}
```