# Multiple Filtering cases in Rust

Tags: rust

I can filter the active classes as follows, but how can I achieve bringing all the classes where their status is **not `Online`**? Status for not active can be `Cancelled`, `Deferred`, or `Optional`.

```
pub enum Status {
    Online,
    Cancelled,
    Deferred,
    Optional,
}

pub struct CustomFilter {
    pub status: Option<Status>,
}

fn example() {
    let mut custom_filter = CustomFilter::default();
    custom_filter.status = Some(Status::Online);
    let online_classes = self.get_classes_with_filter(custom_filter).await?;

    // where Status -> Cancelled, Deferred, Optional
    let non_active_classes = todo!("??");
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my question, would you mind check it again.

Comment: It still does not contain a [MRE]. Please check my comment again for instructions on how to provide one.

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I conditionally check if an enum is one variant or another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51429501/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: And to double-check basics, you know about the `!=` operator, yeah?

Comment: can I write as `Some(Status::!=Active)` ? It is not allowed.

Comment: No. Once you provide a [MRE], I'm sure you'll get useful answers.

Comment: I have added `Status` Enum in the question as well, is that enough?

Comment: what is `Filter`? is it [`std::iter::Filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Filter.html)? doesn't look like it. are you looking for a solution that uses this class?

Comment: I have just added `CustomFilter` struct as well. Updated question accrodingly

Comment: ``cannot find derive macro `Serialize` in this scope``; ``error: cannot find derive macro `Deserialize` in this scope``; ``error[E0424]: expected value, found module self``; ``error[E0728]: `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks``; ``error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `Try`)``

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org), then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How to filter a vector of custom structs in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44662312/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of:

```rust
let foo: Vec<_> = whatever;

let active_classes: Vec<_> = foo.iter().filter(|x| x.status == Status::Active).collect();
let non_active_classes: Vec<_> = foo.iter().filter(|x| x.status != Status::Active).collect();
```

Not sure if this is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is *"Can I store `!Active` or `Cancelled | Deferred | Optional` in an `Status`?"* then the answer is **no**. Maybe if your enum worked like [bitflags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509560/how-to-implement-bitwise-operations-on-a-bitflags-enum) but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

You'd have to store them individually in a `Vec` or something more complicated  like:

```
enum StatusFilter {
    Include(Vec<Status>),
    Exclude(Vec<Status>),
}

pub struct CustomFilter {
    pub status: StatusFilter,
}
```

```
custom_filter.status = StatusFilter::Exclude(vec![Status::Active]);
```

I'd recommend not doing this and use functor-based filtering like [@Luke has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64994905/2189130) if at all possible. Its much more straightforward, more flexible to use and implement, and it follows conventions in the standard library.